# Omitting articles before countable nouns

Tags: articles

It is known that if a noun is countable than an article must be used. However, recently I have come across a very interesting sentence. Here it is: "Kate is daughter of John Taylor." What does leaving out the definite article mean there? Would not it be better if it were  like " Kate is the daughter of John Taylor"?

Comment: "Must be used" is an overstatement. Moreover, your example would be much better if rendered as follows: _Kate is John Taylor's daughter._

Comment: This is called a [bare role noun phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268282/can-predicative-complements-not-be-bare-noun-phrases-in-english-that-is-are-cl)